# How to convert a string of any lenght to a fixed length

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, hash, cryptography

i wanted to convert some strings of different in base 64 into a fixed length string and  convert it back into the original string unlike a hash in JavaScript

i tried searching but i couldn't find anything

Comment: What your question seems to be asking for is something clearly impossible.

Comment: exactly why i asked

Comment: "How can I do something provably impossible" is not a rational question.

Answer (score 0):

you need use a database to map the base64 to your fixed string (hope this fixed length not too short )

Comment: i am trying to make a database with this beening a part of it

Comment: Not a fixed string but rather a fixed *length* string. There is no fixed string.